# How to mock the output of one of my functions for unittests?

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I have a python (django) web application. It uses an external web service (Facebook Graph). All the code for making external (http) calls is wrapped in one extra function (called `facebook_api`), which takes some arguments and returns a parsed dict (it does some logging, checks for errors etc.) Around this function, I have written some code. I want to do some unittests of this code.

How can I "mock" this one function with some known input? i.e. I want to provide some input & output for my facebook_api function (i.e. if you see this input, return this, and if it's this, return that, etc.). I then want to check that my code handles it OK.

I want to provide various different scenarios for my code (what if the API started returning this, or that) and check that my code does what I want. I don't want to actually make external (http) requests.

I tried looking at some mock libraries (e.g.http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/ ), but they always talk about creating class objects, or just checking that something was called. I can't see easy ways to say "Intercept this function, and if the input is A, return X, if it's like D, return B"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Mock's side_effect](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) . For example

```
def my_facebook_api(input):
    if input=='A':
        return 'X'
    elif input=='B':
        return 'D'

facebook_api =  Mock(side_effect=my_facebook_api)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using mockito-python (http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/) with a good success. It allows you to specify behaviour of mocks with simple syntax (straight from their documentation):

```
>>> dummy = mock()
>>> when(dummy).reply("hi").thenReturn("hello")
>>> when(dummy).reply("bye").thenReturn("good-bye")
>>> dummy.hi()
>>> dummy.reply("hi")
'hello'
>>> dummy.reply("bye")
'good-bye'
```

This of course requires that you are able to change object containing facebook_api to mock during testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/):

```
>>> import mock
>>> patcher = mock.patch('django.core.urlresolvers.reverse')
>>> reverse_mock = patcher.start()
>>> reverse_mock.return_value = "/foo/"
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('someview')
'/foo/'
>>> patcher.stop()
```

Few notes:

- `patch` acts as a [function decorator, class decorator or a context manager](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch) (above example could be added to `setUp` method, or use `with` inside test method),
- read [Where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch)